# PHP - Compaire Two Multidimensional Arrays and Append to One Array Accordingly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Today I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out a few things in PHP. As I normally do have the tendency to ramble a bit, I will try to keep my question short but concise. Here's what I'm trying to do.

Array #1 is a multidimensional array containing the results from MySQL query done against a user table in the database. It would look as such:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 79 [firstname] => John [lastname] => Doe [province] => Province [email] => someemail@gmail.com [primaryphone] => 123-456-7890 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 113 [firstname] => Jane [lastname] => Doe [province] => Province [email] => email@gmail.com [primaryphone] => 123-456-7890 ) )
```

Array #2 is another multidimensional array containing the results from a MySQL query done against a membership table in the database that contains the id of the user that is associated with the current group. It looks as follows:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [userid] => 79 ) [1] => Array ( [userid] => 115 ) [2] => Array ( [userid] => 124 ) )
```

What I am trying to do, is for every user returned in array #1, look for a value in array #2 under `[userid]` that matches the value `[id]` in array #1. If a match is found for each user, append the key and value `[ismember] => 1` for that user in array #1 - if there is not a match, then append the pair `[ismember] => 0` to array #1.

I feel that this should be a very simple process, and I'm probably just missing something that is elementary... But I've been going at it for a while now and haven't made much progress. Thank you all for your time and help.

== EDIT ==
The first array is generated by the following MySQL Query:

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        id,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        province,
        email,
        primaryphone
    FROM userstable
";
try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$allusersdetails = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The second array is generated by the query:

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        userid
    FROM membershipstable
    WHERE templateid = :currenttemplateid
";
try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':currenttemplateid', $currenttemplateid);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$templateusers = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: you will need 2 for loops for array #1 and array #2 to match.

Comment: It sounds like you could do this with one MySQL query. Are you only using the 2nd array for this purpose?

Comment: So the two arrays come from different tables. One table is the user's information table, and the other table stores the association between the user's `id` and any group that they are associated with. Right now I am using one query to pull the user's info from the first array, and a second query to return their association with the current group.

Comment: @JohnDoe do you mind editing the 2 queries into the question? i'm sure i can help you work them into a single query.

Comment: Done, sorry for the sloppy code. :P

Comment: @johndoe and I have to say, the formatting on the code is good and and you check for errors on your sql queries so, looks good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the 2 queries with one query like this:

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        u.id,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,
        u.province,
        u.email,
        u.primaryphone,
        (CASE WHEN m.userid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ismember
    FROM userstable AS u
    LEFT JOIN membershipstable AS m ON
      m.templateid = :currenttemplateid AND
      u.id = m.userid
";
try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':currenttemplateid', $currenttemplateid);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$allusersdetails = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This will still pull all users, whether they are members or not but, it will add `ismember` as column.

(the `AS x` part of `userstable AS u` and `membershipstable AS m` just assigns the letter as an alias of the table for the duration of the `SELECT`. Basically, it mostly helps you save on typing but also lets you `JOIN` on tables with columns of the same name.)

Welcome to the wonderful world of Structured Query Languages :D

**EDIT**
And just in case someone comes here trying to do exactly what the question title is asking for but doesn't happen to be querying the database but does have a arrays in the exact format that the OP had:

```
<?php
$array = 
    Array ( 0 => Array ( 'id' => '79','firstname' => 'John','lastname' => 'Doe','province' => 'Province','email' => 'someemail@gmail.com','primaryphone' => '123-456-7890',), 1 => Array ( 'id' => '113','firstname' => 'Jane','lastname' => 'Doe','province' => 'Province','email' => 'email@gmail.com','primaryphone' => '123-456-7890',) )
;
$array2 = 
     Array ( 0 => Array ( 'userid' => '79'), 1 => Array ( 'userid' => '115'), 2 => Array ( 'userid' => '124') );

foreach($array as $key => $userInfo) {
    $isMember = 0;
    foreach($array2 as $user) {
        if($userInfo['id'] == $user['userid']) {
            $isMember = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    $array[$key]['ismember'] = $isMember;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm - as such, I'm convinced that you are either a magician or a deity of some sort... This mere mortal extends his most sincere gratitude and fidelity, my lord. XD

Comment: @JohnDoe lol, you flatter me;) but seriously, SQL is neither magic nor divine power! the evidence is that even i can learn it. read all you can about it! Never let yourself think "it would be cool if SQL/PHP/javascript could do this thing but it seems i'm have to use this big nasty code". There probably is some built-in way, or someone else has already found a nicer way of doing it. Always look around for a solution. Just don't spend too long looking either :D Good luck out there and happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$firstArray = //your first array
$secondArray = // your second array
foreach($firstArray as $fa) {
    $id = $fa['id'];
}
foreach($secondArray as $sa) {
    $userId = $sa['userid'];
}
if($id === $userID) {
    $firstArray['ismember'] = 1;
} else {
    $firstArray['ismember'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This outputs:

` Array (  [9] => Array ( [id] => 131 [firstname] => Jane [lastname] => Doe [province] => Province [email] => email@gmail.com [primaryphone] => 012-345-6789 ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 132 [firstname] => John [lastname] => Doe [province] => Province [email] => email@gmail.com [primaryphone] => 012-345-6789 ) [isnumber] => 0 )'`

So it looks like the if statement is appending `[isnumber]` for the entire array that is one level up from the individual users...

Comment: So what do you exactly want? @JohnDoe

Comment: this code just compares the last `'id'` from the first array to the last `'userid'` from the second array

Comment: @Terminus you are right. This was the solution of first asked question. You answered like a boss, so I have no rights to regret you. "I have failed this question" ;) :P